# Assets folders showing...but no image thumbnails are loading

Tags: ee2, assets, jquery

I'm using EE 2.7.2, PHP 5.3.27, and Assets 2.2.2 and I'm running into a weird issue that I haven't come across.  I'm getting 403 forbidden errors in my javascript console and I check the files on the server and they're there and the permissions are correct.

What I'm trying to do is load the module Assets in the EE CP and it loads the subfolders on the left hand-side but it doesn't load any image thumbnails on the right.  When I try and update indexes, I select a folder or two, and then I push the Update Indexes and it just greys out and doesn't do anything.  I checked my file upload paths and they are correct and I've loaded files in those folders to make sure they load without an issue.  My permission settings on the folders are all 777 and I made sure my cache folder and all folders enclosed were 777.

The red warnings are "POST http://mydomain.com/ 403 Forbidden" against the file "jquery.js?v=1386166017:178"

Any thoughts or help would be great?

(If you're wondering about an .htaccess issue...I use the same .htaccess file on another site...same provider...same plan...and it works...so something went weird on this install.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting HTTP 403, rather than the cross-domain error that most people get, then you might be hitting the incompatible session bug. Assets uses Ajax to do a lot of things and that is processed via Frontend by EE, so if your Control Panel Session and User Session types are not compatible, the Ajax requests will think you're not logged in.

You cna try going to Admin -> Security and Privacy -> Security and Sessions and changing settings for "Control Panel Session Type" to "Cookies and Session Id", and changing "User Session Type" to "Cookies only". This should make sure that if you're authorized in the CP, when you access anything via front-end (such as any of Ajax requests), EE is able to recognise your credentials.